# how to set frame dynamically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

i am trying to set imageview as subview for scrollview.for that i am setting different frame depends upon the screensize.

This is my code

```
 let screensize:CGRect=UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenwidth=screensize.width
        var frames:CGRect
        for var index=0 ;index < arrBirds.count ;index++
            {
                if(screenwidth==320)
                {
                    frames.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * (self.view.frame.size.width);
                    frames.origin.y = 0;

                    frames.size=scrollview.frame.size;

                }
                else if(screenwidth==375)
                {
                    frames.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * (self.view.frame.size.width);
                    frames.origin.y=0;
                    frames.size=scrollview.frame.size;
                }
                else
                {
                    frames.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * (self.view.frame.size.width);
                    frames.origin.y=0;
                    frames.size=scrollview.frame.size;
                }

                imageView=UIImageView(frame:frames)
                imageView.image=UIImage(named: arrBirds[index] as! String)
                scrollview .addSubview(imageView)
```

**But i am getting error this line**

```
  frames.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * (self.view.frame.size.width);//struct frame must be completely initialised  before a member is stored to.
```

Comment: i dont know which one answer is first @luk2302

Comment: you can see that by hovering over the timestamp on the bottom right of each answer - where there is written "answered 2 hours ago" (if you hover it will show you the exact second). Additionally you can order the answers by "oldest".

Comment: yes got it @luk2302 :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not yet created an instance of the struct `CGRect` yet. Before accessing / setting any members on it you you need to create a instance first and **only after that** set the different members of it:

Change the line `var frames:CGRect` to:

```
var frames = CGRectZero
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) :

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an
>   appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or
>   structure is created.

Your `frames` object isn't initialized, instead you should write :

```
var frames = CGRectZero
```